# Qt QWidget::setGeomerty

Tags: c++, qt

i'm stuck with a simple Function of Qt that does not work for me.i made a class that inherits 
from QMainWindow and another class that inherits from QWidget.then i made from the second a member object(a pointer to) inside the first and assigned it as its centralWidget during the construction of my window.

when it comes to adjust my centraWidget inside the window with the function QWidget::setGeomerty() it simply don't work.here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::show() 
{

   //some code that centers my window on the screen

   int margin=this->width()/7;

   centralWidget()->setGeometry(margin,centralWidget()->geometry().top(),this->width()-margin,centralWidget()->geometry().bottom());

   QMainWindow::show();

}
```

i know it might be stupid but i just can't figure it out.help me.

Comment: Usually you'd call `setGeometry` on `MainWindow` I think.

Comment: do you know how to resize the cantralwidget inside the main window?i just tried the Move() and resize() instead of setGeometry() and it don't work too.

Comment: Add a layout? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QMainWindow` has its own layout in which the center area is occupied by the central widget. So it won't be pretty straightforward to break that layout and modify the central widget size / position arbitrarily.
What I recommend is to use a placeholder central widget and add your widget as a child.
I'm pretty sure you can achieve what you want by setting a proper Qt built in layout to the "placeholder" central widget and then adding your widget to the layout.

Comment: i think i was doing just what you said. thank you.bellow is my new and final code:

Answer (score 0):

layouts was necessary to manage what i want; i think it's not possible to hand directly over the central widget and try to move/resize it;but by adding a layout and a child widget, we can dispose of them.here is my code:

mainwindow.cpp

// i focused on my window constructor

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_MainView(new MainView(this)),
    m_WindowLayout(new MainWindLayout(NULL))//my custom layout witch just inherits from QGridLayout

{

```
//.............
setCentralWidget(m_MainView);
m_WindowLayout=new MainWindLayout(m_MainView);//my layout set into my central Widget"m_MainView".
QWidget *temp(dynamic_cast<QWidget *>(m_MainView->centralView()));//centralView() returns a child QWidget of my central Widget 
QMargins margins(this->width()/5,0,this->width()/5,0);//setting up layout margins :left,top,right,bottom;exactly what i need
m_WindowLayout->setContentsMargins( margins);
m_WindowLayout->addWidget(temp,0,0,-1,-1);//adding my child widget to the layout filling all cells of the gridlayout.
```

}

thanks everybody